# Protecting external config file in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, browser, config

I have created an external config.json file for use in a Vue js application that I'm then accessing in code. I want to prevent the file from being accessed directly in a browser (e.g., http://thesite.com/config.json). If I use IIS request filtering to prevent access to .json files, it solves the browser access issue but the Vue application also gets a 404 when trying to access it. Is there a way to allow the Vue application to access this file and server administrators to alter its contents, but prevent end users from accessing it directly in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

No, a Vue app runs code client-side, and need access to the file just like the browser does. You need to run your code server-side, if you don't want to expose a file over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on security through obscurity.

Why are you trying to prevent access to this `config.json` file?

If it is going to be accessed by the Vue client, it will by necessity be accessible to a determined user.

The public client is inherently insecure, and no amount of obfuscation would deter a necessarily determined attacker from accessing the content of the config file provided it is either existing on the client-side or is transferred via the network to the client.

The only way to ensure no public user can access the contents of the `config.json` file is to handle it entirely server-side and process what needs to be done with it there.

Anything that touches the client-side, you should consider as accessible no matter how hidden or obfuscated.